# How to wait until adgroup created in Adwords script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I am creating `video adgroups` in Adwords script using `campaign.newVideoAdGroupBuilder().build()`. I want to publish my newly created adgroup details to my database records, but didn't find a proper way to wait and insert.

Below is my code

```
function adgroup_create(campaign, params){
  var videoAdGroup =
    campaign.newVideoAdGroupBuilder()
    .withAdGroupType(params["adgroup_type"])
    .withName(params["name"])
    .withStatus(params["status"])
    .withCpv(params["cpv"])
    .build()
    .getResult();
  return videoAdGroup;

}

var adgroup = adgroup_create(campaign, params)
//Here I want to get created adgroup_id and insert in my db
Logger.log(adgroup); // showing undefined
```

I tried using `Utilites.sleep(100)` but same I am not able to get the ID and its executing next lines and getting errors.

How to wait until the adgroup is created and to proceed next.

Comment: Documentation uses [`.getResult()`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_videoadgroupoperation#getResult_0). Perhaps implementing this would help you further along.

Comment: @Casper it's already in the script